# How do I give a separate color to the line that is following text when user is typing in textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I hope my question isn't too confusing, this line I speak of is the one circled in the screenshot below:

[image]

I was hoping it was possible to make it a different color from the color of the text in my textarea. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope it will solve:-----

***textarea{
caret-color: red
}***

Comment: Thank you so much I didn't know it was called a caret.